# Can taking Cialis cure Erectile Dysfunction permanently?

Tags: medical-science, sexuality, erectile-dysfunction

Referring to the article "[New Study Shows Men Taking Cialis® (tadalafil) Tablets Once Daily Returned to Normal Erectile Function after Incomplete Response to As-Needed PDE5 Inhibitor Therapy](https://investor.lilly.com/releasedetail.cfm?releaseid=777416)"

> Eli Lilly and Company (NYSE: LLY) announced today that study results
>   published in the Journal of Sexual Medicine showed a greater
>   percentage of men who had an incomplete response to as-needed PDE5
>   inhibitor treatment returned to normal erectile function when given
>   Cialis once daily, compared to placebo, as measured by the erectile
>   function domain of the International Index of Erectile Function
>   (IIEF-EF). In a pre-specified secondary measure, Cialis significantly
>   improved erectile function scores versus placebo in those men who had
>   an incomplete response to as-needed PDE5 treatment.

1. From my understanding, it seems to claim that Cialis has a better chance of curing Erectile Dysfunction ***permanently***, compared with other treatment, am I right?
2. Is this study legit? I am aware that it is published on the Eli Lilly ( the maker of Cialis)'s website, which naturally casts doubts on the objectivity of the study. Is there any other study that backs this sensational findings up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The study is here:

<sub>J Sex Med. 2013 Mar;10(3):844-56. doi: 10.1111/j.1743-6109.2012.02898.x. Epub 2012 Oct 4.</sub>
[Efficacy and safety of once-daily tadalafil in men with erectile dysfunction who reported no successful intercourse attempts at baseline.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23035781)
Shabsigh R1, Seftel AD, Kim ED, Ni X, Burns PR.

#### Potential for long lasting cure

The study shows that in a significant fraction of the cases, Tadalafil was effective post treatment:

> The posttreatment intercourse success rate was 32% and 46% for tadalafil 2.5 mg and 5 mg, respectively, in men with no successful intercourse attempts at baseline.

#### Legitimacy

- The study is funded by the maker of Cialis. This is disclosed.
- The study is published in reputable peer-reviewed journals.
- The study is on ~500 patients. This is not a large scale study, nor it is a review of many studies.
- The study has no citations.